# How to schedule a deferred custom action from an immediate custom action in Wix/DTF?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, dtf

I've seen statements to the effect that it is possible, even commonplace, to reference an immediate custom action from a .wxs file, and to have that custom action schedule subsequent (deferred) custom actions.  What I don't know is what the code looks like that does this.  Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, found the answer myself:

Session.DoAction("ActionName")